# How to deploy a J2EE Client/Server application as a standalone solution?

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, client-server, saas

I'd like to develop a SaaS application using Java EE with JBoss (or GlassFish) and JSF 2.0. Though the final application will be mainly deployed in a standard client/server application, it also needs to be deployable as a standalone application on a local machine (Linux or Windows) for several reasons.

I would prefer not to develop 2 versions of my application (Client/Server and Standalone). Besides I'd also like to avoid setting up manually a complete local server on each client machine to host the application.

Therefore, I'd like to know if there is any solution to deploy easily (with a single installer or a sort of container for example) a Java Client/Server application on a local machine?

Answer (score 2):

For JBoss/Wildfly I would recommend looking at [Wildfly Swarm](http://wildfly-swarm.io/).  Ultimately what it does is create a single `.jar` file that can be run on the command line with something like `java -jar myjarfile.jar`.  You'll still need to figure out how to launch that (and the user will need a JVM installed) but you don't need to install a full server.  You don't mention it but there is [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) that does something very similar if you're using Spring.

Your application will need to pack the client and server side into what will likely be a single `.war` file that will be packaged into the runnable `.jar` file.  You'll also need some way of indicating to the client side application where the server is located - is it localhost or your standard website.

You don't mention if you have any sort of database backend but that would require something like an embedded H2 or Derby database to be included in the "uberjar" to use as a backing store.

Comment: Thx. Yes I do need a database. I thought about using a standard MySQL database. Should I rather use an embedded database also for the standard web application?

Comment: The reason I suggested H2 or Derby was that they are both Java.  MySQL is a native executable which means that you'll need to have separate versions for Linux and Windows.  I'm not convinced that you can package all of that with either Swarm or Spring Boot.  Short of a Docker solution you're getting into a pretty complex deployment.  Do you really need the "on premise" version?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, this is a client requirement to have the platform both as a SaaS and on-premise solution. Initially, he wanted us to develop 2 distinct versions, but it is double work...